# React setState not rerendering with awaited response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, jsx

I am trying to render a component's contents using data fetched from an API.

The API successfully returns data and updates state as shown in the console output, logged at render and by comparing prevState and newState in componentDidUpdate().

However, the new state isn't rendered in the component, why is this?

The content **does render** if I go to another page route e.g. '/' and then back to '/table', but this is not the case when refreshing the page.

Appreciate any help

```js
export default class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTableRows();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('Component did update. Prev: ', prevState, 'New: ', this.state);
  }

  getTableRows = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetchData();
      this.setState({
        data: response,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log('RENDER - props:', this.props, 'state:', this.state);
    return (
        <Container>
          <Table.Body>
            {this.state.data.map(item => {
              return (
                <TableRow
                  key={item.key}
                  response={item.response}
                  approved={item.approved}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Table.Body>
        </Container>
```

**UPDATE:** Additional context

Here's an example of state data:

```
[
  {
    "key": "recBIW8drmVpC8sNT",
    "response": "Example",
    "approved": true,
    "date": "2020-04-02T03:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key": "recWZtUAHf4Z78lP2",
    "response": "Example",
    "approved": true,
    "date": "2020-04-03T20:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key": "recch8GoP59PyftxX",
    "response": "Example",
    "approved": true,
    "date": "2020-03-31T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key": "recg8uRL6RSKroCjZ",
    "response": "Example",
    "approved": true,
    "date": "2020-04-04T22:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key": "recimzyYWbVf1c7WC",
    "response": "Example",
    "approved": true,
    "date": "2020-04-06T01:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Here's how I'm constructing the return object in getData():

```
let data = [];

fetchAirtableData = async () => {
  base('Responses')
    .select()
    .eachPage(
      function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
        // This function (`page`) will get called for each page of records.

        records.forEach(function(record) {
          let key = record.getId();
          let response = record.get('Response');
          let approved = record.get('Approved');
          let date = record.get('Date Submitted');

          data.push({ key, response, approved, date });
        });

        fetchNextPage();
      },
      (cb = err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
      }),
    );

  return data;
};
```

[Here's the output in the console (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRoxb.png)

Comment: could you provide some example data that is put in your state? I see no reason why this would not rerender correctly on a state change

Comment: Updated post with additional context

Comment: Are you cleaning your ```data``` array every time you call the ```fetchAirtableData()``` or just pushing it to the end of existing data?